# Facebook Marketing API Between Relative Dates

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know I can retrieve data from the API between two specified dates like so:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_xxxxxx/insights?level=ad&fields=ad_name,adset_name,campaign_name,spend,unique_clicks,clicks,impressions,cost_per_unique_click,cpm,ctr&sort=spend_descending&time_range[since]=2016-04-01&time_range[until]=2016-04-16
```

Is there a way to retrieve the data from the API using relative dates from today? Such as this psuedocode:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/act_xxxxxx/insights?level=ad&fields=ad_name,adset_name,campaign_name,spend,unique_clicks,clicks,impressions,cost_per_unique_click,cpm,ctr&sort=spend_descending&time_range[since]=15 DAYS AGO&time_range[until]=7 DAYS AGO
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.

We do support a list of date presets

And they are defined in:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-account/insights/

Or you can check our php SDK:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/613d89fbe0424d017a5156658b4e324fbfb5be68/src/FacebookAds/Object/Values/AdsInsightsDatePresetValues.php

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/d51193b19d730ae9274d45540986e1ac311b074d/src/FacebookAds/Object/AdsInsights.php#L72

In curl you will just use date_preset parameter instead of since